# How can I recovery from the error 9030 while mailbox.item.body.getAsync failed?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I'm working on the outlook add-in. But I get the issue that sometimes Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync will failed when the add-in page reloaded. The worst thing is that, once body.getAsync return the error "APICallFailedDueToItemChange", the body.getAsync will be always failed with the same error. 
The detail of this error is {name: "APICallFailedDueToItemChange", message: "The selected item has been changed.", code: 9030}

I tried to recall the getAsync and even reload the whole window to make the add-in restarted, but the error will happen persistently. The only way is switching to another email.

Reproduce steps:
1. Create any outlook add in which try to get the email body
2. after add-in loaded, reload the add-in window
3. Once the 9030 error happened, those code in console will always trigger the same error until I switch to another email

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('text', (result) => {
      if (result.status === 'succeeded') {
        console.log(result.value)
        return resolve(result.value); // updated as suggested by Mavi Domates
      } else {
        console.error(result.error)
        return reject(result.error);
      }
    })
  })
```

I expect the getAsync should work fine even the previous callback is failed, but actual the exception will never be cleaned.

Comment: What client are you testing this on? Windows Win32 Desktop? Outlook Web Access? Etc. Also what specific version?

Comment: Also how are you reloading the add-in window?

Comment: If you are using the SupportsPinning feature. You also need to implement addHandlerAsync for the itemChanged event. Otherwise, calling APIs on the item will result in that error.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT My client is MacOS 10.14.4 outlook 16.24. For reproduce this window, I reloaded the page by right click the add-in and select the "Reload". It happened randomly but about 10 times tries.
I also added the itemChanged event that why switch to another email can recover this issue.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I created a test project in [github](https://github.com/andrewzjl/OutlookAssistant/tree/master/WhatIsImportant). Could you please help to have a look? Thanks
The issue is related to I want to pin that task pane. Before I change the manifest, I tried to reload window about 20+ times, there is no problem. After use the addHandlerAsync related logic, if I pinned the task pane and switched email then reload by right click. Error is reproduced.

Comment: Confirming that this is a bug on Mac Outlook, we are able to reproduce this. It is a Mac-specific issue and we will be fixing this soon. We'll update this space once it is done. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Is the bug still open for this? Is there an issue tracked somewhere that I can follow? We are experiencing the same issue currently in our code - verified that it works in the browser but does not work in Mac Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your code as such, you aren't really doing anything with that promise.

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return window.Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('text', (result) => {
      if (result.status === 'succeeded') {
        console.log(result.value);
        return resolve(result.value);
      } else {
        console.error(result.error);
        return reject(result.error);
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, in my real code of project, I resolved and rejected it. The code I pasted here is for test in console. Somehow, your suggestion makes sense

Comment: Try it out please